# How to load/pause/resume youtube video in Cocoa app?

Tags: javascript, cocoa-touch, webview, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

To load a youtube video is very simple. I use webView;

```
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:kVideoLink];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[self.webview mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

But how to pause/resume the video?
I tried:

```
    [self.webview stopLoading];
    [self.webview reload];
```

OR

```
    [[self.webview mainFrame] stopLoading];
    [[self.webview mainFrame] reload];
```

Both of them doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I called javascript to solve this problem.

There is a example like [CallJS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CallJS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004241)
I try to get the api from [YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Requirements)

but there is a much simpler one: [from jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WPmY/6/)

```
<div id="player"></div>
<a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
<a href="#" id="resume">Resume</a>...
```

thanks.